# Convert tweepy JSON object to dict

Tags: python, tweepy

I'd like to convert the result of a Tweepy `api.trends_location(woeid)` call to a dict (or a dict of dicts), so I can work with the values (really, I want to end up with a dict of the 'name' values). The Tweepy documentation says that the result is 'a JSON object' ([see here](http://joshthecoder.github.com/tweepy/docs/api.html#local-trends-methods)), but when I retrieve it, `type(retrieved)` evaluates to `list`. Sure enough, `retrieved` has a `len` of 1, and `retrieved[0]` gives me a single item:
 `[{'trends': [{'url': 'http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23questionsidontlike', 'query': '%23questionsidontlike', 'events': None, 'promoted_content': None, 'name': '#questionsidontlike'}, ], (more of the same), 'created_at': '2011-01-31T22:39:16Z', 'as_of': '2011-01-31T22:47:47Z', 'locations': [{'woeid': 23424977, 'name': 'United States'}]}]`.

I can call `json.dumps`, which will give a nicely-formatted representation, but that's not much use to me, and `json.loads` gives me: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort_keys'`

How should I proceed?

Link to full code: https://gist.github.com/805129

Comment: JSON objects in Python are in fact represented using `list` and `dict` objects. `dict` is used for objects and `list` for arrays.  What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I understand that, but a list with one member, which is the entire result isn't much use, in this case. I'd like to extract the values of 'name' into their own list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay this should do it!  It is even tested (thanks for posting the additional info).

```
>>> names = [trend["name"] for trend in retrieved[0]["trends"]]
>>> names
['#wishuwould', '#questionsidontlike', '#februarywish', 'Purp & Patron', 'Egyptians', 'Kool Herc', 'American Pie', 'Judge Vinson', 'Eureka Nutt', 'Eddie House']
```

I think most of the confusion came from the documentation referring to the output as a JSON object, which is different than a JSON string which would need to be converted using the `json` module.

How this works: `retrieved` is a list that contains a single item, which is the dictionary that contains the `trends` key, so `retrieved[0]["trends"]` is the list of trend dictionaries, where each trend dictionary contains the `name` key you are interested in.

Comment: I tried this quickly, but am only getting '0' as the output for retrieved[0][0], So something odd is going on. Have edited original with link to full code.

Comment: Okay it looks like the output is still in a string format, I had thought it was already converted to Python objects.  Try `json.loads(retrieved[0])` and see if that works, I'll start editing my comment.

Comment: Hmm, json.loads(retrieved[0]) is giving me a 'expected string or buffer' error, and json.loads(str(retrieved[0])) gives me 'Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)'

Comment: Well I guess my theory is wrong, could you post the entire output of `print retrieved`?  Either here or on github.

Comment: OK, making some progress: type(retrieved[0]) is a dict. Here's the retrieved output (click raw to see it properly): https://gist.github.com/805173

Comment: Check my most recent edit, this should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yep, I just finished testing with a less elegant slice and loop. Nice comprehension, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you?

```
def searchKeys(struct, keys, result = None, recursive = True):
        if result is None:
                result = []

        if isinstance(struct, dict):
                for k in keys:
                        if struct.has_key(k):
                                result.append(struct[k])

                if recursive:
                        for i in struct.values():
                                searchKeys(struct = i, keys = keys, result = result, recursive = recursive)
        elif isinstance(struct, list):
                if recursive:
                        for i in struct:
                                searchKeys(struct = i, keys = keys, result = result, recursive = recursive)

        return result
```

Usage example:

```
>>> searchKeys(struct = a, keys = ['name'])
['United States', '#questionsidontlike']
```

It recursively walks down a `dict`/`list` hierarchy searching for a set of `dict` keys and stores the corresponding values to a `list`.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a Tweepy 'Status' object to a Python dictionary (JSON), access the private member "_json" on the object.

```
tweets = tweepy_api.user_timeline(screen_name='seanharr11')
json_tweets = map(lambda t: t._json, tweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> a = {"response":[{"message":"ok"},{"message":"fail"}]}
>>> json = simplejson.dumps(a)
>>> simplejson.loads(json)
{'response': [{'message': 'ok'}, {'message': 'fail'}]}
```

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html