# Convert dict into tweepy status

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter, tweepy

There are several thread (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900451/convert-tweepy-status-object-into-json) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857235/convert-tweepy-json-object-to-dict)) concerning the ways to convert a `tweepy.Status` object into `json` or `dict`.

Do you have a way to do the opposite? I've scrapped a bunch of tweets and stored them as dicts in a pickle file. Now I'm trying to load them and recreate the `tweepy.Status` object from this dict.

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I already have several functions that take a status as input and I'd rather not have to modify them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tweepy.Status` object is constructed through the classmethod [`tweepy.Status.parse()`](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/models.py#L73-L105), which takes Tweepy's `API` object and a dictionary representing an API response JSON text.

So after you prepare an `API` object, you can construct `Status` object with a dictionary like this:

```
status = tweepy.Status.parse(api, tweet_dictionary)
```